# What kind of "geometric" regularity $f'^2$ gives on $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, uniform-continuity, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

When solving real-analysis' problems I like to represent the functions involved and think geometrically what is going on.

Today I got the following exercise :

> Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, such that : 
>   $$\int_\mathbb{R} \mid f \mid \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   $$\int_\mathbb{R}  f'^2  \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   Proove that $f$ is Hölder continuous.

When I see the assumption involved it's not hard to see that there must be some Cauchy-Schwartz inequality somewhere (because the assumption of absolutely integrable is on the square of the derivative and not only on the derivative itself).

So, with this in mind we easily get the following proof :

> We have (using CS) : 
>   $$ \mid f(x) -f(y) \mid \leq \int_x^y 1 \times f' \leq \sqrt{\int_x^y f'^2}\sqrt{y-x} $$
>   Hence it follows that $f$ is $\frac{1}{2}-$Hölder continous since that $\sqrt{\int_x^y f'^2}$ is bounded.

As you noticed it's not hard to come up with the proof since the assumption of the problem on the absolute integrability of the **square** of the derivative of $f$ directly leads to thinking we must use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

The problem is that I don't like this way of thinking. That's why I am seeking a geometric intuition of the problem.

For example, if we only have the assumption of absolute integrability on $f'$ instead of $f'^2$ does the result still holds?

Why the fact that: $\int_\mathbb{R}  f'^2  \in \mathbb{R}$ imply so much regularity for $f$ ?

$\ldots$

Comment: The answer on the last question is because it's a one-dimensional case. The general answer is given by embedding theorems of Sobolev spaces

Comment: @Andrew This is interesting. I would love to hear more about that. Also do you have a counterexample that answer question 1 ?

Comment: For $p=1$ the statement doesn't hold, concider a function with $f'$ having high narrow spikes s.t. $|f'|$ is integrable. As for imbedding theorems see Morrey inequality  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey's_inequality in your case $n=1$, $p=2$.

Comment: @Andrew I guess it is possible but this is not that easy since we also need $f$ to be integrable. With narrow spike, it means that $f$ is going to vary a lot on small intervals. Hence we need to control $f$ and $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is assumed to be $C^1$ the integrability of $(f')^2$ isn't really giving you additional regularity. On any compact interval $[a,b]$ you have by the mean-value theorem
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x-y| \sup_{z \in [a,b]} |f'(z)| \le \left( |b-a|^{1/2}\sup_{z \in [a,b]} |f'(z)| \right) |x-y|^{1/2} $$
so that $f$ is *locally* Holder continuous. The problem is that you lose control of the Holder constant as the interval $[a,b]$ gets large. The integrability condition on $f'$ provides you a way to obtain uniform control over the constant.

Comment: To me this is only a partial answer. For example you are not answering why we must have the integrability on the *square* of the derivative and not on the derivative only. Also it’s explicitly written « geometric » in the title which means adding example of functions is better I guess for the OP. Here you are only saying that : it helps controlling everything when the interval gets large. Why ? Counter-example when we have integravility only on $f’$ ? ...